# "Error: PIRLS step-halvings failed to reduce deviance in pwrss" with Generalized Linear Mixed-Effects Models

Tags: r, glm, mixed-models

Hello everyone and thank you for helping!

I am trying to run this model but I get this error:

```r
M_MAR <- glmer(CLASS.1_2_3. ~ DISTANCE * TREATMENT * FAxSmean * SRxS + ROUND + 
    (1 | SITE/PLANT_CODE), family = binomial, 
     na.action = "na.fail", data = STR_SRFA_MAR)
```

> Error: (maxstephalfit) PIRLS step-halvings failed to reduce deviance in pwrssUpdate

`class` is a binomial factor;
the other explanatory variables are continuous and categorical
I would like to run the `dredge` function after.

If I remove two explanatory variables between the ones I want to test for an interaction it works, but I would like to test more interactions at the same time using `dredge`.

[SUMMARY(STR_SRFA_MAR)][1]

```
 APE    :194   Min.   :  0.00   Length:1519        APE_FRA_B_NET_D5_W1 :  12   Min.   : 0.020  
 HOOG   :194   1st Qu.: 25.00   Class :character   HOUT_FRA_A_NET_D5_W2:  11   1st Qu.: 1.170  
 ZUN    :175   Median : 50.00   Mode  :character   HOOG_FRA_B_NET_D2_W2:  10   Median : 7.535  
 MAR    :159   Mean   : 48.66                      ROO_FRA_A_NET_D1_W2 :  10   Mean   : 9.010  
 APP    :150   3rd Qu.: 80.00                      ROO_FRA_B_NO_D4_W1  :  10   3rd Qu.:14.557  
 ROO    :138   Max.   :105.00                      ROO_FRA_B_NO_D5_W1  :  10   Max.   :55.340  
 (Other):509                                       (Other)             :1456   NA's   :1       
      TSS        MALFORMATIONS.A_B_C.  CLASS.1_2_3.        DATE           EATEN.1_2_3_4.  OTHERS 
 Min.   : 1.10   A   :616             Min.   :0.0000   Length:1519        Min.   :1.000   0:927  
 1st Qu.: 5.80   B   :264             1st Qu.:0.0000   Class :character   1st Qu.:1.000   1:592  
 Median : 7.60   C   :153             Median :1.0000   Mode  :character   Median :2.000          
 Mean   : 7.56   NA's:486             Mean   :0.5286                      Mean   :1.944          
 3rd Qu.: 8.90                        3rd Qu.:1.0000                      3rd Qu.:3.000          
 Max.   :26.60                        Max.   :1.0000                      Max.   :4.000          
 NA's   :638                                                              NA's   :1447           
 TREATMENT ROUND     D            AB             DISTANCE_TOG      DISTANCE_F     FAxSmean     
 NET:749   W1:711   D1:356   Length:1519        Min.   :  0.00   30     :200   Min.   : 104.1  
 NO :770   W2:808   D2:350   Class :character   1st Qu.: 25.00   0      :184   1st Qu.: 393.2  
                    D3:261   Mode  :character   Median : 50.00   5      :172   Median : 704.8  
                    D4:275                      Mean   : 46.17   25     :150   Mean   :1630.1  
                    D5:277                      3rd Qu.: 75.00   75     :148   3rd Qu.:1519.1  
                                                Max.   :100.00   50     :140   Max.   :8506.5  
                                                                 (Other):525                   
    FAxDsum             SRxS            AGRI            GRAS             SN              WB        
 Min.   :    0.2   Min.   : 4.00   Min.   : 3.00   Min.   : 7.00   Min.   : 4.00   Min.   : 1.000  
 1st Qu.:   21.0   1st Qu.: 9.00   1st Qu.:14.00   1st Qu.:13.00   1st Qu.: 8.00   1st Qu.: 1.000  
 Median :  128.6   Median :13.00   Median :24.00   Median :21.00   Median : 8.00   Median : 4.000  
 Mean   : 1571.5   Mean   :13.56   Mean   :23.62   Mean   :24.69   Mean   :14.31   Mean   : 5.562  
 3rd Qu.:  727.1   3rd Qu.:18.00   3rd Qu.:30.00   3rd Qu.:40.00   3rd Qu.:15.00   3rd Qu.: 5.000  
 Max.   :23389.5   Max.   :23.00   Max.   :52.00   Max.   :49.00   Max.   :37.00   Max.   :31.000  
                                                                                                   
    BUILT_UP    
 Min.   : 3.00  
 1st Qu.: 5.00  
 Median :11.00  
 Mean   :19.73  
 3rd Qu.:29.00  
 Max.   :56.00  

'''

    


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7fH1.png
```

Comment: Unfortunately we probably can't help you without a [mcve].  Scaling and centering your numeric predictors *sometimes* helps. Can you tell us more about your data set (e.g. `summary(STR_SRFA_MAR)` ?

Comment: of course: it consists of 1519 obs. Class is marketable strawberries (=1) and non marketable strawberries (=0), distance is continuous (0,5,30,35,50,55,70,75,100,105m), treatment is factor (net, no), FAxSmean is numeric (mean flower area cover per site), SRxS is numeric (species richness per site), round is factor (R1, R2) and plant code (more or less 400) is nested into site (11). I added a picture of the summary of the data set.

Comment: Can you please add your summary information in a *text* format (cut and paste into a code block delimited by ``` ) rather than as a screenshot?  It would also help to convert your character vectors into factors first, as then the summary will show us something about the distribution of observations across levels ...

Comment: Does a simpler model (additive, i.e. `DISTANCE + TREATMENT+ FAxSmean + SRxS` , or with only two-way interactions, i.e. `(DISTANCE+ TREATMENT + FAxSmean + SRxS)^2`), work?

Comment: a simpler model and a two-way interactions work!